# How to set all values of a specific attribute to lowercase in pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am using pymongo to update attributes in a mongodb database. 
I have an attribute gender, which contains, for example, male MALE and Male, and i need those to match.
I have tried:

```
mongo_collection.aggregate([{ $project: { Gender:{ $toLower:"$Gender"}, src:1}}])
```

but it said the sytax was invalid.

Let me know if you have any insight on why the syntax is invalid?

Comment: What's the error message? Can you post the full trace?

Comment: I just ran it in python n it just said invalid syntax. it didn't give me anything else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using pymongo 3.6 and have been doing such queries there. I think the first mistake is you haven't enclosed '$toLower' in quotes ''. If you haven't defined Gender variable somewhere you might need to enclose that as well in quotes. For me the working syntax is below -

```
mycoll.aggregate([{'$project':{'itemName':{'$toUpper':'$item'},'itemNo':1}}])
```

If i leave  $toUpper without quotes , it tells me invalid syntax at $ and i think its same what you are encountering.

Comment: My code still isn't working, but I believe you are right in that it has to do with the gender variable; I no longer get a syntax error. Thank you very much for your help!